# backslash issue running .exe file

Tags: python, windows, backslash, spyder

I have made a very very simple script in python:

```
import os


path = str(os.getcwd())+'\\'+'INSTALLER PYTHON'+'\\'+'python-2.7.6.msi'
os.startfile(path)
```

Then, I have made an .exe file of it, and when I try to run it in windows I get this error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File"<string>", line 12, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\INSTALLER PYTON\\python-2.7.6.msi'
```

BUT....in Spyder, if I do like this:

```
import os


path = str(os.getcwd())+'\\'+'INSTALLER PYTHON'+'\\'+'python-2.7.6.msi'
print path
#os.startfile(path)
```

I get this nice output:

```
'C:\Users\Desktop\TestFolder\INSTALLER PYTON\python-2.7.6.msi'
```

Which is exactly what I want so...

what is wrong with the backslash and the double backslash?

Comment: Have you noticed that you've also got typos in the folder name? `INSTALLER PYTON`

Comment: it was my error writing it here, sorry but the script is correct, I checked

Comment: You can also take a look at `os.path.join`. In your case `path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'INSTALLERPYTHON', 'python-2.7.6.msi')`. This will intelligently join the strings adding `/` or `\\` depending on the operating system.

Comment: very good one, I didn't know, THANKS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **subprocess**.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call([path,arguments1,arguments2,arguments3,...])
```

Note that arguments are `optional`. If your executable requires/takes `commandline` arguments as input, you can pass them in argument field.

For more info: [DOCS](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

You can also use `os.system()` however subprocess is prefered